# Single Part App Pages in SharePoint Online does not work if user has not the autorisation to modify the page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

In a modern SharePoint Site, I have many Sigle Par App Pages. They work well when I am logged with my admin autorisations.

But when I test them with a user wich has not the autorisation to modify the pages, the pages are not shown like a single part app page but like another page !

Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever users with lower privileges cannot see a change, you should immediately suspect that something hasn't been published. This goes for Modern as well as classic master page/page layout scenarios.

So go publish the page and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !